# Why is the App Actions Test tool crashing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, actions-on-google

I am investigating Google actions by following [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions/#0) code lab

the version of Android Studio I am employing is this:-

```
Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Canary 9
Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.8473230, built on April 19, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 10.15.7
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry:
    external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
    ide.text.editor.with.preview.show.floating.toolbar=false

Non-Bundled Plugins:
    com.android.aas (3.5.1)
```

I have installed the App Actions Test Tool plugin (3.5.1)

however when I attempt to open the App test tool I receive the following stacktrace

```
update failed for AnAction(com.android.aaassistant.AppActionsAssistantSidePanelAction, id=AppActionsServices.ConnectionAssistant) with text=Help

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'boolean com.android.tools.idea.connection.assistant.ConnectionAssistantBundleCreator.isAssistantEnabled()'
    at com.android.aaassistant.AppActionsAssistantSidePanelAction.update(AppActionsAssistantSidePanelAction.java:14)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performDumbAwareUpdate$0(ActionUtil.java:131)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareUpdate(ActionUtil.java:145)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.doUpdate(ActionUpdater.java:637)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$updateActionReal$7(ActionUpdater.java:129)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$callAction$9(ActionUpdater.java:200)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$0(ProgressManager.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:188)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeProcessUnderProgress$12(CoreProgressManager.java:624)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:646)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:623)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:175)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.runProcess(ProgressManager.java:57)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater.lambda$callAction$10(ActionUpdater.java:198)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionUpdateEdtExecutor.lambda$computeOnEdt$0(ActionUpdateEdtExecutor.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.lambda$expandActionGroupFastTrack$3(Utils.java:256)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.runLoopAndWaitForFuture(Utils.java:582)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroupFastTrack(Utils.java:254)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.expandActionGroupImpl(Utils.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.fillMenu(Utils.java:278)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenuInner(ActionMenu.java:362)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.Utils.performWithRetries(Utils.java:620)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.fillMenu(ActionMenu.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenu.lambda$new$0(ActionMenu.java:75)
    at java.desktop/sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit$CancelableRunnable.run(LWCToolkit.java:677)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:303)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.AWTThreading$4.dispatch(AWTThreading.java:218)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:776)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:891)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:760)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:447)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:818)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:446)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:805)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:498)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

where have I gone wrong?

is it not possible to use the App Actions Test Tool plugin anymore?

How can I resolve this issue?